# Failing to search multiple buffers in Emacs using "icicle-search-buffer" and C-RET

Tags: search, emacs, icicles

I am trying to use the `icicle-search-file`/`icicle-search-buffer` commands, but am having the same problem with both where <kbd>C-RET</kbd> seems to perform no operation on completion options once I have already entered the search context pattern.

The operations described are using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 13.10 with [`icicles`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), [`workgroups2`](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2), and some custom key bindings all done with <kbd>H-_</kbd> or <kbd>C-c _</kbd> to avoid conflicts. I have `icicles` and `workgroups2` set to be on at start in my `.emacs` file. I don’t have anything custom bound to <kbd>C-c `</kbd>.

I have learned to use `icicle-search` (<kbd>C-c `</kbd>) with progressive completion (<kbd>S-SPC</kbd>) and it works well, which is why I wanted to figure out these commands.
I have called the `icicle-search-buffer` command with each of these options just to be sure there is no difference, and the result are the same:

- <kbd>C-9</kbd> <kbd>C-c `</kbd>
- <kbd>M-s</kbd> <kbd>M-s b</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `icicle-search-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I enter the search regex (`.*` <kbd>RET</kbd> - to make things simple) just as with `icicle-search`, and am then prompted for the buffers to search. I move through the completion options with arrow keys and use <kbd>C-RET</kbd> on the buffers I want to search. The result of this is the buffer I chose disappearing from the completion list and no obvious result appearing. Hitting <kbd>RET</kbd> at any point just searches the buffer I had active before beginning the search, just as if I had used <kbd>C-c `</kbd>. It does not search the currently selected buffer in the completions list.

*Does anyone see where I am failing to understand the usage of these commands?* I have read through the information on the [Icicles - Search Commands, Overview](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) page.

The "Search Multiple Buffers, Files, and Bookmarks" section seems to describe this simply, but beyond using <kbd>C-RET</kbd> not much is said that suggests to me where my problem is.

I also followed the link in that section to the [Icicles - Multi-Commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) page
which was helpful in seeing how `icicles` modifies vanilla Emacs commands and how multi-commands work in general, but I could not determine from that where my mistake is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for asking a clear, well-researched question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing nothing wrong.  (And your description of using **Icicles** search is a good one.)
I introduced a ***bug*** recently.

Should be OK now.  Please download the latest version of [`icicles-mac.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/icicles-mac.el).  Or wait (up to a day) for it to be mirrored on MELPA and download it from there.  Sorry for your trouble, and thanks for bringing this to my attention.

---

***IMPORTANT:***

If you byte-compile **Icicles** (recommended), then ***whenever*** (as now) **`icicles-mac.el`** is updated, you
***must load*** `icicles-mac.el` (*not* just `icicles-mac.elc`), then ***compile*** it, then ***recompile ALL***of the other **Icicles** source files as well.  You want to make sure that all byte-compiled files are up-to-date.

This is normal for Lisp.  Code that depends on macros needs to be byte-compiled anew after loading the updated macros.

---

Comment: Got it, thanks for the reply. Finding my issue was a useful problem to bring attention to as opposed to a mistake in usage is no problem. I have been using the package tool and MELPA so I will plan to do this tomorrow evening and confirm the fix.